Azure - How to create External Identities and assign them to users with Terraform
I am trying to create External Identities with Terraform and assign them to users in Azure.
My first problem is that I am not able to find the resource External Identities in Terraform.
My second problem is, that I am not sure how to link the external Identity with the user.
The user has been created with the resource type azuread_invitation.
Thanks in advance :)
My Code so far is only the azuread_invitation that I am creating. For the External Identity I have no idea how to create it:
variable "invited_users" {
  type = map(object({
    name  = string
    groups = list(string)
  }))
}

resource "azuread_invitation" "invited_users" {
  for_each = var.invited_users

  user_email_address = each.key
  redirect_url       = "https://portal.azure.com"
  user_display_name  = each.value.name

  message {
    body                  = "Invitation to my tenant"
    additional_recipients = ["test@mail.com"]
  }
}


any code you tried so far? please share the info by editing the query @MarvinCore

@VinayB - I added my code in my query. However there is only my way to create the azuread_invitation. For the External Identity I still dont have any idea how to create it. I hope this helps. Thanks in advance :)


Create Identities and assign them to users with Terraform

I have gone through the documentation of hashicorp to understand the creation of external users using terraform is by as per the suggestion is the only way to achieve this is using azuread_invitation from there we can using azuread_group_member.
Code:
# Invite external user
resource "azuread_invitation" "example" {
  redirect_url = "https://portal.azure.com"
  user_email_address = "prathikj@hashicorp.com"
}
   
resource "azuread_user" "invited_user" {
  user_principal_name = "prathikj@M365x79976744.onmicrosoft.com"
  display_name = "prathikj"
  password            = "testPrathik@sswd99!"

  depends_on = [ azuread_invitation.example ]
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "example" {
  group_object_id = azuread_group.example.object_id
  member_object_id = azuread_user.invited_user.id
}


Output:


